# adding a callback to this function

Tags: jquery, function, callback

Would someone mind giving me a hand and help me out by taking a look at this function and explaining how i could add and execute a callback function after last element is finished fading in. I'm not sure how i'm suppose to fit it in or rework the code to get the result i'm looking for.

code is here [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Pvmq/)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a callback is nothing more than passing a function as an argument, and calling that function at a certain time. As a side note, I suspect you want all `.item` elements, but `.next` doesn't care about the original selector. http://jsfiddle.net/4Pvmq/6/

```
$(function(){
    elFadeIn('.item', function() {
        alert("done");
    });
});

function elFadeIn(selector, callback) {
    var $items = $(selector);

    // this is the function that's going to be called recursively
    (function fade(i) {
        var $elem = $items.eq(i);

        if($elem.length) {  // there is an element
            $elem.fadeIn('slow', function() {  // fade it
                fade(i + 1);
            });
        } else {  // no elements left
            callback();
        }
    })(0);  // start with first
}
```

Comment: really well setup and what i'm looking for. thanks. One other questions though. Is it possible to reverse the order in this and fade out from the last element all the way to the first?

Comment: @Koder: Using `.fadeOut`, `i - 1` and starting with `$items.length - 1` should work.

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly a pretty answer, but one approach is simply to assess whether there is, or is not, a `next()` element and re-call the function or perform a different action:

```
function elFadeIn(elem) {
    elem.fadeIn('slow', function() {
        if ($(this).next().length) {
            elFadeIn($(this).next());
        }
        else {
            alert('finished');
        }
    });
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4Pvmq/1/).

And a slightly prettier way of writing that would be:

```
function elFadeIn(elem, callback) {
    elem.fadeIn('slow', function() {
        var next = $(this).next(),
            action = next.length ? elFadeIn(next) : alert('finished!');
    });
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4Pvmq/8/).

Comment: +1 Beat me to it lol, I'd personally store `$(this).next()` in a var to don't create 2 jQuery objects and transverse the DOM twice for the same thing - http://jsfiddle.net/4Pvmq/3/

Comment: Yeah, I was working towards that with the second example. And thank you! =)

Comment: Updated version is just perfect. `=]`